# HTML CSS Alignment inside td

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing some custom CSS with Jquery-UI date picker.

I have one requirement to display a dot below each date on calender to indicate some kind of ratings:

[image]

I am creating the dots dynamically as:

```
  <strong>.</strong>
```

I want to display all the dots closed to the dates like Sunday 1, but I cannot find a way to dynamically align each dots with every date.

Comment: Provide us an [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), please.

Comment: here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6pER9/1/

Comment: What are you trying to do? put the dots in the grey bit? - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/6pER9/2/

Comment: I think what you want is to replace your line tds[j].innerHTML += '<strong style="color:#081ae4">.....</strong>'; with $("a", tds[j]).append('<br/><strong style="color:#081ae4">.....</strong>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to put the dots inside your grey bit then you can change your js code (I noticed you are using jQuery so have rewritten to use it):

```
var table = $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").eq(0);
var tds = table.find("td");

tds.each(function(i) {
    var link = $(this).find('a');
    if (link.length > 0) {
        var rating = 5; // add your rating functionality here
        switch (rating)
        {
            case 1:
                link.addClass('dot one');
                break;
            case 2:
                link.addClass('dot two');
                break;
            case 3:
                link.addClass('dot three');
                break;
            case 4:
                link.addClass('dot four');
                break;
            case 5:
                link.addClass('dot five');
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

and use the following styles:

```
.dot.one:after {content:'.';}
.dot.two:after {content:'..';}
.dot.three:after {content:'...';}
.dot.four:after {content:'....';}
.dot.five:after {content:'.....';}
.dot:after {display:block; color:#081ae4; font-weight:bold;}
```

This way your click functionality won't lose the date - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/6pER9/5/)

Comment: But here is one Problem, when i click on date, it alerts (NaN/NaN/Nan).
how to fix this

Comment: @Dot_NETJunior Sorry, you must have missed the edit - See new fiddle above